# A question about non consecutive sum writing

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

I am very confused and I thank you in advance for your help about a very stupid question. I would write a summation sequence of non consecutive primes $a,b,c,d...$ greater than $3$ with a distance of $d\geq{3}$ between each others. So, what would be the correct mathematical writing?

$$\cfrac{b}{a_{i-2}+c_{i-1}+\ldots+d_{i}}=x$$

or

$$\cfrac{b}{\sum_{i\geq3}^{n}a_{i}a_{1}+\ldots+a_{n}}=x$$

Comment: I am really sorry to ask such stupid question

Answer (score 1):

Actually your question is not clear. As I understand, if $\{p_i\}$ is a sequence of non consecutive  primes greater than $3$ with at least a distance of $3$ between each others, then the summation is $\displaystyle \sum_{p_i>3 \;\text{and}\; p_i-p_j\geq 3;\;\text{for}\;i\neq j}p_i$

Comment: the distance $d\geq{3}$ thank you

Comment: so you suggest this $$\cfrac{p'}{\displaystyle \sum_{p_i>3 \;\text{and}\; p_i-p_j\geq 3;\;\text{for}\;i\neq j}p_i}=x$$

Comment: What is $p'$ here?

Comment: $p'$ instead $b$ the other prime over the fraction.

Comment: In fact, the sum concerns only the divisors.

Comment: Ok, in the original problem, what do you have to write as $x$?

Comment: $x$ has no significant role right here. I think that this is new and I didn't found good references in the literature.